# anRichment package is missing

Tags: bioinformatics, genetic

I'd like to try and use anRichment for WGCNA annotation. Unfortunately the site to download the install files seems to be down. Does anyone have the installation files?

https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/GeneAnnotation/Tutorials/anRichment-Tutorial1.pdf

source("https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/GeneAnnotation/installAnRichment.R"); installAnRichment();

I've previously installed this, but the package disappeared when I updated R. Now I want to install and it's no longer available